# How can drive sdk log into different account?

Tags: google-drive-api

Once a account logged-in in a browser, the drive sdk seems to use that account. How my installed app can connect to the drive with a different account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the account you want to authorize for, pass the `user_id` parameter to the authorize URL, set the value to the account you want to authorize as.

Comment: Is the user_id the account name or email address?